# Calender Booking System

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to create an booking system using ASP.net in Visual Studio VB I am using the calendar and I am briefly aware of the calendar controls. But I want to know how can I add a database behind a calendar is that possible? or not?

I ideally want the calendar booking times and then extra information.so they all need to read in form one another.